# htaccess how to rewrite this url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

How to rewrite this URL:

```
https://example.com/illustrations.php?category=cats&cat_id=1
```

to:

```
https://example.com/category/cats
```

also, how do I still preserve `cat_id` param?

I tried this but it does not work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?category/(.*?)/?$ /illustrations.php?category=$1 [L]
```

Comment: "it does not work" - What happens exactly? Your directive looks "OK". "still preserve cat_id param" - what do you mean exactly? Given the URL `/category/cats` then the only thing you can do is to seemingly hard-code the `cat_id` parameter in the _substitution_ string. Otherwise, you need to include the cat_id in the URL. "How to rewrite this URL..." - it's the other way round, you are rewriting _that_ URL to _this_ URL (which is what you are doing in your `.htaccess` rule).

Comment: If you want to preserve the cat_id parameter it needs to be part of the new URL pattern too. So maybe `https://example.com/category/cats/1`. Without that there is no way to implement a working redirection since the rewriting module cannot somehow make up such ids by magic.

Comment: @MrWhite When I add this code and go to illustrations.php?category=cats  it does not change the url in the browserbar.

Comment: @arkascha and how would I achieve this?

Comment: What URL are you linking to in your application/site?

Comment: I fail to understand your question to my comment. I gave a clear example. So what sense does it make to ask "how would I achieve that?" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I add this code and go to `illustrations.php?category=cats` it does not change the URL in the browserbar.

Yes, that is "correct".

The code you posted *internally rewrites* the URL `/category/cats` (which is the URL you should be linking to in your HTML source) back to the actual filesystem/URL path: `/illustrations.php?category=cats`. This is required in order to make the "pretty" URL `/category/cats` "work".

You can't change the URL structure using `.htaccess` only - if that is what you are implying. You do need to actually change the physical URLs in your HTML source.

You could implement an *external redirect* (not a rewrite) from `/illustrations.php?category=cats` to the canonical URL `/category/cats` using `.htaccess`, but note that this is only to benefit SEO (and third parties that might have already linked to the old URLs). This is a necessary *additional* step if you are changing an existing URL structure and SEO is a concern, but it is not part of the "working" of your site.

> how do I still preserve `cat_id` param

You would need to include the *value* of the `cat_id` parameter in the URL. eg. `/category/cats/1` (as @arkascha suggested in comments) or `/category/1/cats` - depending on which value is more important. I would put the more important value first, since URLs can be accidentally cropped when shared.

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^/?category/(.*?)/?$ /illustrations.php?category=$1 [L]
> ```

This rule could be simplified. Filesystem checks are relatively expensive. It looks like you could remove both of these by making your regex more specific. eg. Could `/category/1/cats` ever map to a file? Do you need directories to be accessible? I would expect the answer to both those questions is "no".

I would also decide on whether to allow trailing slashes or not, rather than allowing both (as in your current rule). Strictly speaking this creates *duplicate content* (two URLs; same content), so requires additional steps to resolve. Your example URL(s) do not contain a trailing slash.

So, you could simplify your rules to the following in order to rewrite `/category/1/cats` (no trailing slash) to `/illustrations.php?category=cats&cat_id=1`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/(\d+)/([\w-]+)$ /illustrations.php?category=$2&cat_id=$1 [L]
```

This assumes `cat_id` can be 1 or more digits (`0-9`). And `category` is limited to the following characters: `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore), `-` (hyphen).

With regex it is preferable to be as restrictive as possible. By omitting the dot (`.`) from the last path segment in the above rule it cannot match a physical file (assuming all your files have file extensions).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I'm new to working with htaccess. So I think I did not understand the concept of htaccess. I would like to thank you for explaining it so nicely.